# Mantaflow not working in 2.82 release

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have repeatedly tried setting up a simple flow and domain liquid simulation in 2.82. Following tutorials very closely. The strange thing is it works like 1 time in 6 build attempts.

But most times there are no particles after bake.

On the rare occasion that there was I saved the file, but when I opened it again it was not working.

Is anyone else having this trouble?

Thanks
Murph

Comment: Welcome Murph! I think that's worth to file a bug report over at https://developer.blender.org/